# Google Chrome crashes without any log

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I wrote a Chrome pop-up extension and it works fine. But when click else where to close pop-up, it crashes Chrome. I tried looking at both the locations mentioned in this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/624/where-is-google-chrome-crash-dump-located) to see if some info is available as to why it is crashing to fix this issue, but the directories are empty! Is there a way I can find out why it is crashing? Following are the errors I get.

> **Google Chrome has stopped working**
>
> A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will
> close the program and notify you if a solution is available.

and then I get another window saying

> Whoa! Google Chrome has crashed. Relaunch now?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This page](http://dev.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines/reporting-crash-bug) explains how to get a crash ID and other crash data, which you can then attach to a [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/entry). You may need to enable crash reporting in "Preferences" -> "Under the Hood "-> "Automatically send usage statistics and crash reports to Google" to have crash IDs be generated and appear in `chrome://crashes`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but on that page, the first link requires MSDN account and the second one is giving an installer that is for Windows SDK. I started that but did not see windbg.exe anywhere which is needed according to that page. Have you tried this?

Comment: Most of the instructions on the page are not necessary with recent versions of Chrome, where crash IDs are displayed on chrome://crashes. Do you see any crashes listed there?

Comment: So what if i want to inspect crash information but not share it with google?

Answer (score 4):

In newer versions of chrome you need to go into settings/privacy and enable  "Automatically send usage statistics and crash reports to Google" and then after the next time it crashes you should see the log appear in chrome://crashes

Answer (score -2):

To remove or disable Chrome extensions,

Open the Chrome browser
Type “chrome://extensions/” in the address bar (URL bar)
Press the Enter key
Now, you’ll see all the extensions in a panel form
You can click on ‘Remove’ to uninstall them
You can toggle an extension off to disable it

Comment: Why would you want to uninstall the extension? Op is trying to fix the bug, not getting rid of their own work.