# Where can I find the Chrome Extension Crash report?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, crash

note: It's the *Extension* crash report, NOT Chrome itself crash report

I developed a chrome extension only in javascript, but it crashes sometimes. I've grep my dir and find nothing, google search doesn't help either.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764253/google-chrome-crashes-without-any-log

Checkout.