# chrome://crashes log is empty after crash?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, crash

There is an internal page in our company where- in idle state ( doing some background js operation)  causes - *chrome to crash*.

Quick research shows that chrome://crashes should show the log after a crash.

I already checked this :

[image]

So when I caused the browser to crash via :

- `new Uint8Array(1e8)`
- or using this :

  `txt = "a";
  while(1){
      txt = txt += "a";    //add as much as the browser can handle
  }`

– I did see :

[image]

But the log was empty  : ( checked also after restart the browser)

[image]

Even the crashes is empty :

[image]

My chrome version : Version 36.0.1985.143 m

**Question**

How can I successfully log crashes  ? what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: somewhat related here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764253/google-chrome-crashes-without-any-log

Comment: @Mahan already read it. Edited.